# How to use `next` for redirect to another function in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and i am using expressjs,Right now i am trying to use middleware function but how can we redirect to another function using "next" , Her is my current code

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Check if user is authenticated
  const isAuthenticated = checkAuthentication(req);

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    // Now you have verified the has valid a token. So how can we redirect to another function
    next();
  } else {
    // User is not authenticated, send an unauthorized response
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, 
the `next()` function itself tells nodeJS to keep walking through middlewares untile reaching the last middleware provided function of the expressJs API. 
So I did not undersand exactly what do you mean by "redirecting to another function" ? do you mean to forward your request to another API Callback ? or you want to keep going until reaching the last server Response ?

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez lets suppose user is authticated successfully then what should be next step ? means user should redirect to another function ( for go to dashboard or other pages further), hope you understand my point

Comment: well now I understand your question.. in this case you are talking to a "view redirection", so this of course depends on your project setup: if you are using view engines like EJS or Handlebars ? or you want a static page redirection ? or something else (like using frontend framework as Angular or React) ?

Comment: Note that `next()` doesn't tell "Node" to do anything, it tells _Express_ what to do, based on the fact that it's a critical part of [Express middleware functionality](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).